Can the existence of singletons be proven using first order logic and ZFC set theory?
By singleton I am not talking about a set of the form S = {x} where x is any particular element. I am talking about an actual element x that is not part of any set. So the idea is to distinguish between Sets(collections of objects without self-membership)and elements, which stand alone and have no elements or subsets themselves.

Your question is very incomprehensible to me. What do you mean a singleton whose element is not part of any set?

These objects are usually called urelements or atoms, and they do not exist under the usual $\mathsf{ZFC}$ axiomatization. There are variants of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ where they are allowed.

Thanks Andres Caicedo. That's precisely what I was inquiring about. Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Perhaps you can edit the title, then? Because the answer is obviously true. We can prove that singletons exist in $\sf ZFC$. But that's not the question that you seem to have asked.
